# How to filter rows in pandas dataframe where a column has a value equal to some value of a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with two columns: one for ID_number and one for week_number. 
It can look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_number':[13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15,16], 'week_number':[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5]})

#   ID_number   week_number
#0  13  1
#1  13  2
#2  14  1
#3  14  2
#4  14  3
#5  15  1
#6  15  4
#7  16  5
```

I want to select for every different ID, those ID where the week value is 2 and 3 and then make a label for the data. If an ID does not have week 2 AND 3, I label it with a 1. Else, I label it with a 0.

For now, I came around with a rather non elegant solution, that works, but I am sure that there must be another way:

```
def check_courier_week(df, field, weeks):
    weeks_not_provided = weeks
    new_df = df
    new_df['label'] = np.zeros(len(df))
    for c in np.unique(df[field]):
        tmp = df[df[field] == c]
        if len(np.unique(tmp.week_number.isin(weeks_not_provided))) == 1 and np.unique(np.unique(tmp.week_number.isin(weeks_not_provided))) == False:
            new_df['label'][df[field] == c] = 1
        else:
            new_df['label'][df[field] == c] = 0
    return new_df
```

Any ideas on how could this be improved? I guess there might be a solution using groupby, but I cannot think how to implement it.

The resulting label sould be:

```
#   ID_number   week_number     label
#0  13  1   0.0
#1  13  2   0.0
#2  14  1   0.0
#3  14  2   0.0
#4  14  3   0.0
#5  15  1   1.0
#6  15  4   1.0
#7  16  5   1.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use groupby, you can then use the minimum and the maximum per group of week number to determine the value of the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer how you could use groupby: You could group by ID_number and then just find a label that way, IE:

```
df1['label'] = np.zeros(len(df))
grouped_table = df1.groupby('ID_number')
groups = list(set(df1['ID_number']))
for group in groups:
    test_list = list(set(grouped_table.getgroup(group)))
    if (2 in test_list) & (3 in test_list):
        df1.loc[df1['ID_number'] == group]['label'] = 0  
    else:
        df1.loc[df1['ID_number'] == group]['label'] = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `groupby` with `transform` `any`

```
(~(df1['week_number'].isin([2,3])).groupby(df1['ID_number']).transform('any')).astype(int)
Out[39]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
Name: week_number, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) without grouping:

```
unique = df1.loc[df1['week_number'].isin([2,3]), 'ID_number'].unique()
df['label'] = np.where(df1['ID_number'].isin(unique), 0, 1)
```

Or:

```
df['label'] = (~df1['ID_number'].isin(unique)).astype(int)
```

---

```
print(df)
   ID_number  week_number  label
0         13            1      0
1         13            2      0
2         14            1      0
3         14            2      0
4         14            3      0
5         15            1      1
6         15            4      1
7         16            5      1
```

Answer (score 2):

While not efficient, you can utilize `set` operations via [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.isdisjoint):

```
def checker(x):
    return set(x).isdisjoint({2, 3})

df1['flag'] = df1.groupby('ID_number')['week_number'].transform(checker)

print(df1)

   ID_number  week_number  flag
0         13            1     0
1         13            2     0
2         14            1     0
3         14            2     0
4         14            3     0
5         15            1     1
6         15            4     1
7         16            5     1
```